# How to say tradeoff in Cantonese and Mandarin?

Tags: mandarin, cantonese

The word **tradeoff** is not listed in Google nor in CantoDict.

Is it 折衷?

1. What's the Cantonese translation?
2. What's the Mandarin translation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Trade-off https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/trade-off
>
> *1 : a balancing of factors all of which are not attainable at the same time*
>
> *2 : a giving up of one thing in return for another : exchange*

Trade-off as a noun is 代價 in both  Cantonese and Mandarin ('trade-off' basically means "in exchange" )

Example:

"Thicken the armor would provide better protection, but the **trade-off** is your speed would slow down."

"加厚护甲会提供更好的保护，但**代價**是你的速度会减慢。"

You can use "作為交換" (in exchange) instead of "代價是" e.g. "加厚护甲会提供更好的保护，但**作為交換**, 你的速度会减慢。"

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you will find one Chinese equivalent for trade-off. In English you could also use disadvantage, downside, drawback, handicap, problem, weak point, trouble, nuisance, flaw.

I like 权衡 but I would not limit myself to that for a translation.